# AltGr (Right Alt) key not being recognized on my Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, keyboard-layout

EDIT2: This is the (relevant) output for the command 'xev'

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0x50f, subw 0x0, time 777849246, (-866,1007), root:(464,1094),
state 0x90, keycode 113 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 64
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

EDIT: This is the output for the following command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

```
['altwin:menu', 'compose:rctrl', 'grp:win_space_toggle', 'lv3:ralt_switch', 'lv3:alt_switch']
```

First of all, I have seen some threads with similar issues, and I have tried some of the suggestions to no avail. I have come up with a partial solution that is "working" but it is quite uncomfortable, so I was wondering if anyone else could shed some light on this problem.

I am connecting via Citrix to a desktop that runs Ubuntu 22.04.1 As I am used to type in a Spanish keyboard, I have changed the system language to Spanish and I have a Spanish keyboard myself. However, there are two things that I have noticed, first, that the layout for Spanish keyboard does not correspond to my Spanish keyboard layout - there are a few keys that simply do not match - and the second one which is the one that is causing me trouble is the fact that I cannot use my Alt Right key to access to 3rd level as I normally would.

As I said before I have tried a few solutions, the first one being selecting Right Alt from keyboard settings directly, but this does not work.

I read about how to change the keyboard layout to match my particular keyboard settings by doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. This did not work either for Right Alt.

Finally, what has more or less helped was to install gnome-tweaks and in "Additional Layout Options", select under "Key to choose the 3rd level" another key - because when I select anything with "Right Alt", it simply does nothing if I am testing it in the terminal, if I test in my RStudio environment, it does a sort of "backwards tab" - I don't know how else to describe it. My gnome shell version is 42.5

My thoughts right now are that maybe I did not select the RIGHT configuration for my specific keyboard - it's a Spanish Corsair Platinum K95 if that's of any use? Or that maybe the fact that I am connecting remotely via Citrix is somewhat messing the keyboard input, because I can tab out to my desktop by doing Alt+Tab or Win+Tab

If anyone had any ideas that I might have not tried, I would be very happy to hear them.

Thanks,

Alejandra RS

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Done! my understanding is that because I am using Tweaks to set lvl3 to any alt, this is why it shows both right alt and left alt, right? So this means that either of them should work, doesn't it?

Comment: Ok, `xkb-options` does not contain anything which would obviously explain your issue. OTOH, most of the stuff is redundant AFAICT. It may be worth to clean it up to see if the 'option overflow' possibly has anything to do with it. To do that, you can run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:rctrl']"` and then reboot.

Comment: I tried to do this ; there ain't any changes - the right alt option is still not working. Now when I run the first command, the output is ['compose;rctrl'] only.

Comment: You can try the `xev` command, press and release the <Right Alt> key, and let us know the relevant resulting output by editing your question again.

Comment: Done! I think I have chosen the right info to show, but just in case I have a .txt file with the whole output in case I didn't.

Comment: I see `ISO_Level3_Shift` which is expected for a key defined to access 3rd and 4th level symbols. So I'm not able to see what is wrong. Maybe someone else can help you.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Directly setting **AltGr** to right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:ralt_switch']"
```

**Warning**: This will clear any other setting you might already have for `xkb-options`.

To check existing settings;

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

### Solution 2

You could do this graphically as well. Go to `settings` → `keyboard`. Click on `Alternative Characters Key`. Then deselect the `Use layout default` to enable the options below. Choose `Right Alt` from the list.
[image: Alternative Character Key dialogue box]

#### Finally

Check `gsettings`,

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

It should looks like this; `['lv3:ralt_switch']` if there no other keys were set as `xkb-options`.

---

### Note 1

1. Make sure your **Compose Key** configuration do not clash with **Alternative Characters Key** (**AltGr**) config.
   [image: Part of Keyboard Settings dialogue box]
2. Also, be careful your graphical settings tool can sometimes create conflicts after trying out several different options.

   For example, the `gsettings` *might* look like this; `['compose:ralt', 'lv3:lalt_switch', 'lv3:ralt_alt']`
   *Explanation of the example*; two keys (Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right <kbd>Alt</kbd>) are used as `lv3` (AltGr), and `compose` also is using the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

   The solution is to clean-up before proceeding further. By;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:ralt_switch']"
```

### Note 2

One can often confuse `Compose` to `AltGr`. They do not equal to each other. They enable different capabilities.